# Google App Engine development server slow in Windows but not in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: google-app-engine, development-environment, performance

In Ubuntu, I run the command ./dev_appserver.py to start the development server. Everything runs snappy under Linux.

I also have Windows 7 installed on the same machine. In Windows, I start the development server from the Google App Engine Launcher (version 1.5.1). The server appears to start up OK, but once it is running, pages may take minutes before they **begin** to load, if at all. The page tends either to load completely or not at all. If the page does start loading, it's usually fairly quick. It's not the loading of images and scripts that is slow, but it seems like the request itself is getting hung up or lost somewhere.

The page that seems to time out most often is the pretend "Login with Google" page. Also, during hang ups, occasionally I will get the following log message (but I'm not sure that its related). Most times, I won't get any message at all.

```
INFO     2011-07-10 22:36:58,631 dev_appserver_index.py:254] Updating C:\Users\Eric\Documents\NetBeansProjects\linkpad\index.yaml
```

While waiting for a hung request, the Windows Task Manager will show GoogleAppEngineLauncher.exe as using 00 CPU.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Note: I am somewhat dependent on Windows for testing in--you guessed it--IE

**EDIT:**
I have not been able to solve this problem, so I have decided to workaround in Ubuntu:

1. Install VitualBox OSE
2. Get 2 copies of XP and 1 of Win7

   - These can be free if your school has an MSDNAA program. Try googling "yourschool msndaa."
3. Create virtual machines in VirtualBox as follows:

   - XP1 - install IE 7
   - XP2 - install IE 8
   - Win7 - install IE 9

Make sure you have 30GB of free space and at least 2GB ram before going the virtualization route.

Comment: I'm the SDK on Win7 and it's plenty snappy. I don't use the launcher though, just the command line.

Comment: I tried the command line, and unfortunately requests are still getting hung. Especially at the pretend login screen. Good idea though.

Answer (score 3):

Are you viewing you site with Chrome when on windows? If so you may want to start chrome with the `--disable-preconnect` flag.

The single-threaded nature of dev_appserver.py doesn't sit well with some of Chrome's clever connection/request fetching.

There are issues about it [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=59881) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4716), please star if it affects you

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your cpu and increase your RAM and clean up your windows. Windows uses more resources than linux.

Especially with all those background tasks, services and preloaded apps actively competing for resources under Windows. Let's see, you probably have these services, tasks or preloadeds:

Oracle's not-for-commercial-use development db server, persistently active malicious file, s/w, cookie detector, 
Flash, OpenOffice, Java Hotspot/update, $5/month Fax, pdf printer, Picassa, msn/aol, find-a-russian-bride-notification (jest kiddin) ... etc.

Every time a new Java update is performed, sun/oracle insist on ensuring their java update notification is preloaded thereafter. There's an urban legend that says that a certain (US) Republican senator once said, “A billion here, a billion there, and pretty soon you’re talking real money”. Therefore, no matter how little resources publishers of preloaded s/w say they use, they all add up. Disable MSN, Flash, Open Office, etc. I'm sure you are more savvy than I am in these windows creepy annoyances.

When I upgraded from dual core to quad core and from 2GB to 6 GB, the difference in performance of eclipse between Windows and Ubuntu narrowed to an undetectable difference. Every now and then eclipse on Windows still freezes up. I think the optimal set-up to run eclipse on windows is 6 CPUs 12 GB RAM - because I normally run two instances and sometimes even three instances of eclipse. And then occasionally netbeans as well.

I also increased jvm max heap size to 1024 MB, though eclipse never seems to touch that amount of VM.

Comment: I keep my windows box clean (I use autoruns often). I have plenty of expensive metal in there. I don't use eclipse.